# Java Generics Argument Type mismatch going from class generic to method generic

Tags: java, generics, casting

I've got an abstract class with class-level generic types `<O, P>`. In it, I've got a method that accepts an `O`, and a `BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String>`.  The `<B>` generic is defined on the method.

```
public interface ParamDescription<O, P> {
    //...
    <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString);
}
```

I then have three classes that implement that interface in different ways, but all of them have `Class<O>` and `Class<P>` variables. Two have some extra class-level generic types too, and the `Class<>` variables to go with them. In all of them, I'm trying to call that objectToString method using an object of one of the class-level generic types and it's associated class variable.

Here's the simplest one:

```
Function<? super O, P> getter;
Class<P> paramClass;
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get this:

```
error: method apply in interface BiFunction<T,U,R> cannot be applied to given types;
        return objectToString.apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
                             ^
  required: B,Class<B>
  found: P,Class<P>
  reason: argument mismatch; P cannot be converted to B
  where B,O,P,T,U,R are type-variables:
    B extends Object declared in method <B>getParamString(O,BiFunction<B,Class<B>,String>)
    O extends Object declared in class ParamDescriptionSingle
    P extends Object declared in class ParamDescriptionSingle
    T extends Object declared in interface BiFunction
    U extends Object declared in interface BiFunction
    R extends Object declared in interface BiFunction
```

In this example, I could solve it by changing the `B`s to `P`s. However, that doesn't work for the other two implementations. In the other two implementations, I need to use some generic types that the interface doesn't know about.

The only real restriction I have is that the `Class<B>` parameter provided to the BiFunction should correspond to the `B` parameter also given to it.  Basically, "here's an object, and here's its type."

I tried creating a helper function like this

```
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    return paramToString(obj, objectToString);
}
public String paramToString(O obj, BiFunction<P, Class<P>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
}
```

But it didn't like the casting on the BiFunction.

I also tried actual casting like this:

```
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply((B)getter.apply(obj), (Class<B>)paramClass);
}
```

But that gives unchecked cast warnings for both casts, and I don't know enough to know if it's actually safe or not.  My understanding is that it'd basically just cast the first thing to Object, and the second to Class

**Is the casting and suppressing warnings the way to go or is there a better way?**

For reference, here are my other two implementations:

```
//Class level: <O, E, P extends Collection<? extends E>>
Class<O> objClass;
Class<P> paramClass;
Class<E> entryClass;
Function<? super O, P> getter;
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    P collection = getter.apply(obj);
    if (collection == null) {
        return objectToString.apply(collection, paramClass);
    }
    return collection.stream()
                     .map(e -> objectToString.apply(e, entryClass))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
                     .toString();
}
```

and

```
//Class level: <O, K, V, P extends Map<? extends K, ? extends V>>
Class<O> objClass;
Class<P> paramClass;
Class<K> keyClass;
Class<V> valueClass;
Function<? super O, P> getter;
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    P map = getter.apply(obj);
    if (map == null) {
        return objectToString.apply(map, paramClass);
    }
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> objectToString.apply(e.getKey(), keyClass),
                                        e -> objectToString.apply(e.getValue(), valueClass)))
              .toString();
}
```

**Update 1 with more things that I tried, that didn't work:**

I tried setting the target:

```
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.<P>apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
}
```

But that still gives

```
required: B,Class<B>
found: P,Class<P>
reason: argument mismatch; P cannot be converted to B
```

I tried using a wildcard instead of `B`:

```
public String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<?, Class<?>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
}
```

with the same results:

```
required: CAP#1,Class<?>
found: P,Class<P>
reason: argument mismatch; P cannot be converted to CAP#1
```

It's looking like explicitly casting and suppressing warnings might be the only way.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <B> String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<B, Class<B>, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply((B)getter.apply(obj), (Class<B>)paramClass);
}
```

That's frustrating, though, because I then lose the compile-time check that the provided class (2nd parameter) represents the class of the 1st parameter. But it does work, and it does behave correctly otherwise.

**Update 2 with what I went with**
Since casting was the only way I could get it to actually work and that removes the check mentioned just above, I decided to just get rid of the generic type `B` altogether.

My interface has this:

```
String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<Object, Class, String> objectToString);
```

and my implementations look like this:

```
public String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<Object, Class, String> objectToString) {
    return objectToString.apply(getter.apply(obj), paramClass);
}
```

and

```
public String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<Object, Class, String> objectToString) {
    P collection = getter.apply(obj);
    if (collection == null) {
        return objectToString.apply(collection, paramClass);
    }
    return collection.stream()
                     .map(e -> objectToString.apply(e, entryClass))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
                     .toString();
}
```

and

```
public String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<Object, Class, String> objectToString) {
    P map = getter.apply(obj);
    if (map == null) {
        return objectToString.apply(map, paramClass);
    }
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> objectToString.apply(e.getKey(), keyClass),
                                        e -> objectToString.apply(e.getValue(), valueClass)))
              .toString();
}
```

Then, in my call to these functions, I have to suppress warnings, but that's because of how I'm creating the BiFunction. I am creating it using another method that takes in a method generic `P` and `Class<P>`, which is being cast to an `Object` and raw `Class` for the BiFunction. In my opinion, though, that's better than having to cast and suppress warnings every time the BiFunction is used.

In summary: I made it work, but I wasn't able to do it in a way that provided the protections I wanted.

Comment: Why do you need `Class<B>` when you have an instance of `B` already? Can't you just do `obj.getClass()`?

Comment: I need to know the class even if the object is null. 
But also, since it's generics all over the place, would obj.getClass() still work right? For some reason, I was under the impression that it wouldn't.

Comment: I see. If `obj` can be null, then `getClass` would not work. All three classes you showed here seem to force `B` to be `P`. Is there any implementation of the interface where `B` is something else?

Comment: Oh I see what you are trying to do! Let me rethink. Can you show how you would call `getParamString`?

Comment: In all three there are calls where `B` needs to be `P`, but in the second two, there are also calls where `B` would need to be `E`, `K`, or `V` sometimes.

Comment: The call looks like this: `String value = paramDescription.getParamString(obj, (p, c) -> objectToString(p, c, seen));`  In this case, `seen` is a variable keeping track of objects converted, and `objectToString` does a bunch of standard stuff for converting the parameter to a String.  The `ParamDescription` describes a parameter in the given `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't use a generic type `B` on that method.

Details:
There is no way to tell the compiler that, for a given call, the `P` (or some other generic type) should be considered `B`, other than casting:

```
return objectToString.apply((B)getter.apply(obj), (Class<B>)paramClass);
```

However, since you're explicitly casting, you lose the guarantee that the provided class (2nd parameter) represents the class of the 1st parameter.  The only purpose of defining the `B` generic type is to get this protection. So it's best to just not use a generic here and have that argument be a `BiFunction<Object, Class, String>`.

```
String getParamString(O obj, BiFunction<Object, Class, String> objectToString);
```